# RecyclerView has no LayoutManager Android

Tags: android, android-layout, android-recyclerview

I'm trying to show data in fragment using RecyclerView but it keep showing error RecyclerView has no LayoutManager

Here is my Adapter

```
    public class FilmAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<FilmAdapter.FilmViewHolder> {

    private List<Film> mFilmList;
    private Context context;

    public FilmAdapter(List <Film> FilmList) {
            mFilmList= FilmList;
    }


    public static class FilmViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
        ImageView foto;

        public FilmViewHolder(View v) {
            super(v);
            foto = (ImageView) v.findViewById(R.id.posterFilm);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public FilmAdapter.FilmViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent,int viewType) {
        View mView = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.grid_film, parent, false);
        FilmAdapter.FilmViewHolder mViewHolder = new FilmAdapter.FilmViewHolder(mView);
        return mViewHolder;
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(FilmViewHolder holder, int position) {
        Picasso.with(context).load("http://ecinema.esy.es/img/" + mFilmList.get(position).getBackdropPath()).resize(200, 250).into(holder.foto);
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return mFilmList.size();
    }
}
```

Fragment

```
   public class NowPlayingFragment extends Fragment implements RecyclerItemClickListener.OnItemClickListener{
    ApiInterface mApiInterface;
    private RecyclerView mRecyclerView;
    private RecyclerView.Adapter mAdapter;
    private RecyclerView.LayoutManager mLayoutManager;
    public static MainActivity m;

    @Nullable
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_now_playing, container, false);
        String idKota = m.getIdKota();
        mRecyclerView = (RecyclerView) v.findViewById(R.id.rootLayout);
        mLayoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(this.getActivity());
        mRecyclerView.setLayoutManager(mLayoutManager);
        mRecyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);
        mApiInterface = ApiClient.getClient().create(ApiInterface.class);
        mAdapter = new KotaAdapter(new ArrayList<Kota>());
        mRecyclerView.setAdapter(mAdapter);

        Call<List<Film>> call = mApiInterface.getFilmPlaying(
                idKota
        );
        call.enqueue(new Callback<List<Film>>() {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(Call<List<Film>> call, Response<List<Film>> response) {
                List<Film> movies = response.body();
                Log.d("Retrofit Get", "Jumlah data : " +
                        String.valueOf(movies.size()));
                mAdapter = new FilmAdapter(movies);
                mRecyclerView.setAdapter(mAdapter);
            }

            @Override
            public void onFailure(Call<List<Film>>call, Throwable t) {
            }
        });

        mRecyclerView.addOnItemTouchListener(new RecyclerItemClickListener(getActivity(), this));
        return v;
    }

    @Override
    public void onItemClick(View childView, int position) {

    }

    @Override
    public void onItemLongPress(View childView, int position) {

    }
}
```

activity_main.xml

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
    tools:context="com.ecinema.sekaranindyaputri.ecinema.MainActivity"
    tools:showIn="@layout/app_bar_main">

    <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
        android:id="@+id/rootLayout"
        android:layout_width="368dp"
        android:layout_height="495dp"
        android:layout_above="@+id/bottom_navigation"
        android:orientation="vertical"/>

</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

fragment_now_playing.xml

```
    <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context="com.ecinema.sekaranindyaputri.ecinema.Home.NowPlayingFragment">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">
        <ViewFlipper
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="113dp"
            android:id="@+id/slideFilm">
        </ViewFlipper>

    </LinearLayout>

    <ProgressBar
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/progressBar"
        android:layout_centerInParent="true"
        android:visibility="gone"/>
    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true">

        <GridView
            android:id="@+id/gridPlaying"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="400dp"
            android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
            android:layout_marginBottom="0dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
            android:background="@color/colorPrimary"
            android:clickable="true"
            android:columnWidth="150dp"
            android:drawSelectorOnTop="true"
            android:focusable="true"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:horizontalSpacing="5dp"
            android:numColumns="auto_fit"
            android:stretchMode="columnWidth"
            android:verticalSpacing="5dp" />

    </RelativeLayout>

</android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView>
```

grid_film.xml

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="#fff"
    android:id="@+id/filmLayout">

    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="165dp"
        android:layout_height="150dp"
        android:id="@+id/posterFilm"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true" />

</LinearLayout>

Logcat

05-08 19:44:05.852 30270-30270/com.ecinema.sekaranindyaputri.ecinema E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                                                                                   Process: com.ecinema.sekaranindyaputri.ecinema, PID: 30270
                                                                                   java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.ecinema.sekaranindyaputri.ecinema/com.ecinema.sekaranindyaputri.ecinema.MainActivity}: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #1: RecyclerView has no LayoutManager
                                                                                       at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2423)
                                                                                       at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2483)
                                                                                       at android.app.ActivityThread.access$900(ActivityThread.java:153)
                                                                                       at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1349)
                                                                                       at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
                                                                                       at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148)
                                                                                       at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5441)
                                                                                       at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                                                                                       at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:738)
                                                                                       at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:628)
                                                                                    Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #1: RecyclerView has no LayoutManager
                                                                                       at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:543)
                                                                                       at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:427)
                                                                                       at com.ecinema.sekaranindyaputri.ecinema.Home.NowPlayingFragment.onCreateView(NowPlayingFragment.java:48)
                                                                                       at android.app.Fragment.performCreateView(Fragment.java:2220)
                                                                                       at android.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:973)
                                                                                       at android.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1148)
                                                                                       at android.app.BackStackRecord.run(BackStackRecord.java:799)
                                                                                       at android.app.FragmentManagerImpl.execPendingActions(FragmentManager.java:1537)
                                                                                       at android.app.FragmentController.execPendingActions(FragmentController.java:325)
                                                                                       at android.app.Activity.performStart(Activity.java:6319)
                                                                                       at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2386)
                                                                                       at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2483) 
                                                                                       at android.app.ActivityThread.access$900(ActivityThread.java:153) 
                                                                                       at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1349) 
                                                                                       at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
                                                                                       at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148) 
                                                                                       at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5441) 
                                                                                       at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
                                                                                       at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:738) 
                                                                                       at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:628) 
                                                                                    Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: RecyclerView has no LayoutManager
                                                                                       at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView.generateLayoutParams(RecyclerView.java:3737)
                                                                                       at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:506)
                                                                                       at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:427) 
                                                                                       at com.ecinema.sekaranindyaputri.ecinema.Home.NowPlayingFragment.onCreateView(NowPlayingFragment.java:48) 
                                                                                       at android.app.Fragment.performCreateView(Fragment.java:2220) 
                                                                                       at android.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:973) 
                                                                                       at android.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1148) 
                                                                                       at android.app.BackStackRecord.run(BackStackRecord.java:799) 
                                                                                       at android.app.FragmentManagerImpl.execPendingActions(FragmentManager.java:1537) 
                                                                                       at android.app.FragmentController.execPendingActions(FragmentController.java:325) 
                                                                                       at android.app.Activity.performStart(Activity.java:6319) 
                                                                                       at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2386) 
                                                                                       at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2483) 
                                                                                       at android.app.ActivityThread.access$900(ActivityThread.java:153) 
                                                                                       at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1349) 
                                                                                       at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
                                                                                       at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148) 
                                                                                       at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5441) 
                                                                                       at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
                                                                                       at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:738) 
                                                                                       at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:628)
```

I try to search the error and they said to add

```
mRecyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);
```

But it still error. Can anyone help please? Thanks in advance

Comment: don't use nested child elements inside RecyclerView itself, rather use another layout and inflate it. refer to this [post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33969443/why-is-it-saying-recyclerview-has-no-layoutmanager-when-there-is-one-please-s)

Comment: @whenthemorningcomes do you mean RecyclerView in activityMain?

Comment: No, what's the deal about the RecyclerView inside fragment_now_playing.xml? Where are you inflating this view?

Comment: @whenthemorningcomes i delete the RecyclerView in fragment but it still error RecyclerView has no LayoutManager

Comment: Can you post code snippet of grid_film.xml file? If possible, please post logcat information also.

Comment: @whenthemorningcomes i added the grid_film.xml and logcat

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/143695/discussion-between-when-the-morning-comes-and-sekar-anindya).

Comment: fragment_now_playing.xml has wrong parent as i can see you have RecyclerView as parent when recyclerView is not a viewgroup so you can't declare child under recyclerview

Comment: @RajeshKushvaha i change the adapter and the fragment but the error still the same

Answer (score 0):

Where does mRecyclerview come from? isn't it supposed to be recyclerview?

Comment: private RecyclerView mRecyclerView;

Comment: What happens if you use recyclerview and not mRecycleview?

Answer (score 0):

Solve the error by changing the adapter to

```
 public class FilmAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<FilmAdapter.FilmViewHolder> {

    private List<Film> mFilmList;
    private Context context;

    public FilmAdapter(List <Film> FilmList) {
            mFilmList= FilmList;
    }

    @Override
    public FilmViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent,int viewType) {
        View mView = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.grid_film, parent, false);
        FilmViewHolder mViewHolder = new FilmViewHolder(mView);
        return mViewHolder;
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(FilmViewHolder holder, int position) {
        Picasso.with(context).load("http://ecinema.esy.es/img/" + mFilmList.get(position).getBackdropPath()).resize(200, 250).into(holder.foto);
    }

    public static class FilmViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
        public ImageView foto;

        public FilmViewHolder(View v) {
            super(v);
            foto = (ImageView) v.findViewById(R.id.posterFilm);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return mFilmList.size();
    }
}
```

And the fragment to

```
    public class NowPlayingFragment extends Fragment implements RecyclerItemClickListener.OnItemClickListener{
    ApiInterface mApiInterface;
    private RecyclerView mRecyclerView;
    private RecyclerView.Adapter mAdapter;
    private RecyclerView.LayoutManager mLayoutManager;
    public static MainActivity m;
    String idKota = m.getIdKota();

    @Nullable
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_now_playing, container, false);

        mRecyclerView = (RecyclerView) v.findViewById(R.id.rootLayout);
        mLayoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(this.getActivity());
        mRecyclerView.setLayoutManager(mLayoutManager);
        mRecyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);
        mApiInterface = ApiClient.getClient().create(ApiInterface.class);
        mAdapter = new FilmAdapter(new ArrayList<Film>());
        mRecyclerView.setAdapter(mAdapter);
        refresh();

        return v;
    }

    public void refresh() {
        Call<List<Film>> call = mApiInterface.getFilmPlaying(
                idKota
        );
        call.enqueue(new Callback<List<Film>>() {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(Call<List<Film>> call, Response<List<Film>> response) {
                List<Film> FilmList = response.body();
                Log.d("Retrofit Get", "Jumlah data : " +
                        String.valueOf(FilmList.size()));
                mAdapter = new FilmAdapter(FilmList);
                mRecyclerView.setAdapter(mAdapter);
            }

            @Override
            public void onFailure(Call<List<Film>>call, Throwable t) {
                Log.e("Retrofit Get", t.toString());
            }
        });

        //mRecyclerView.addOnItemTouchListener(new RecyclerItemClickListener(getActivity(), this));
    }

    @Override
    public void onItemClick(View childView, int position) {

    }

    @Override
    public void onItemLongPress(View childView, int position) {

    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

*Place*

```
mRecyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);
```

*before*
mRecyclerView.setLayoutManager(mLayoutManager);

Answer (score 0):

Remove the Relative Layout inside the  recycler view. live the recycler view free from other Layout or editor input tags