# How to scroll whole activity

Tags: android, android-layout, android-recyclerview, scrollview

I wrote an application and home page is LinearLayout and is in Fragment. In this LinearLayout there are two RecyclerViews and SearchBar etc. I want to scroll whole activity. I spent 2 days for it but cannot succeed. How can I do that in easy way? There are lots of adapters and connections in that LinearLayout. How can I achieve that without broke any code.
I want to scroll whole activity.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33969443/why-is-it-saying-recyclerview-has-no-layoutmanager-when-there-is-one-please-s

Comment: can you please share your code or sample code here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Set ***Scroll/NestedScrollView*** as a parent view in xml to scroll whole layout.

Add below attribute in recycler view to stop recycler scroll:

```
android:overScrollMode="never"
```

Try below code:

```
 <android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView
                    android:id="@+id/navigation_nested"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:fillViewport="true"
                    android:overScrollMode="never">

                <LinearLayout
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:orientation="vertical"
                    android:padding="@dimen/margin_15">

                    <TextView
                        android:id="@+id/video_tv"
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/margin_15"
                        android:drawableLeft="@drawable/ic_video_tutorial"
                        android:drawablePadding="@dimen/margin_20"
                        android:fontFamily="@font/poppins"
                        android:paddingLeft="@dimen/text_15"
                        android:text="@string/videos"
                        android:textColor="@color/blackTextColor"
                        android:textSize="@dimen/text_15" />


                    <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:overScrollMode="never" />
                </LinearLayout>
            </android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView>
```

Answer (score 2):

You just add this line:

```
//java
yourRecyclerView.setLayouManager(new LinearLayoutManager(this));

//kotlin
yourRecyclerView.layoutManager = LinearLayoutManager(this)
```

or from xml:

```
 app:layoutManager="androidx.recyclerview.widget.LinearLayoutManager"
```

Notice that there is not only `LinearLayoutManager`. If you are using a Grid `RecyclerView` than you might want to use `GridLayoutManager`

Comment: Thank you for your answer. The error  disappeared but I can't see LinearLayout components now, they dissapeared too. There was bunch of components in the LinearLayout but when I put them into RecyclerView they disappeared. How can I solve that? Thanks in advance

Comment: can you update the question to be more clear. I didn't quite got what you said

Answer (score 1):

I solved the problem.
Just write `ScrollView` over the `LinearLayout`

```
<ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <LinearLayout>
      .....
    </LinearLayout>

</ScrollView>
```